# react-native fail to handle error in try catch block

Tags: ios, react-native

i am trying send  image with fetch() function.  Showing red screen and. 'no such file or directory' error before send data.  try catch block is not handling this error.

> 019-02-11 22:35:00.375
>   [error][tid:com.facebook.react.NetworkingQueue][RCTNetworking.mm:272]
>   Error processing request body: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
>   Code=260 "The file “5325CBBA-340E-4227-AE17-5D42021DF648.jpg” couldn’t
>   be opened because there is no such file."
>   UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9362AC50-7C82-4C8D-B686-39A6718CBA5F/data/Containers/Data/Application/64CD29E3-2BD9-4D9A-B168-4B12A848889C/Documents/images/5325CBBA-340E-4227-AE17-5D42021DF648.jpg,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x600003c0a790 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain
>   Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

How to handle this error ?

error screen: https://i.hizliresim.com/bVvqrm.png

```
  VeriListele() {

    try {
      db.transaction((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql("select * from " + TABLO_DATA + " where " + ROW_GONDERILDI_ + "=0", [], (tx, results) => {
          console.log("Query completed2");

          // Get rows with Web SQL Database spec compliance.
          console.log(results.rows);
          var len = results.rows.length;
          const data = new FormData();
          for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            try {
              let row = results.rows.item(i);
              console.log(row);
              var FotoString='';
              if (row.resim1!='' && row.resim1!='undefined') {
                var resimjson=JSON.parse(row.resim1);
                FotoString+='&photo[]='+row.resim1;
                data.append('photo1[]', {
                  uri: resimjson.uri,
                  type: resimjson.type, // or photo.type
                  name: 'photo'
                });
              }
              if (row.resim2!='' && row.resim2!='undefined') {
                FotoString+='&photo[]='+row.resim2;
                var resimjson=JSON.parse(row.resim2);
                data.append('photo1[]', {
                  uri: resimjson.uri,
                  type:resimjson.type, // or photo.type
                  name: 'photo'
                });
              }
              if (row.resim3!='' && row.resim3!='undefined') {
                FotoString+='&photo[]='+row.resim3;
                var resimjson=JSON.parse(row.resim3);
                data.append('photo1[]', {
                  uri: resimjson.uri,
                  type: resimjson.type, // or photo.type
                  name: 'photo'
                });
              }
              if (row.resim4!='' && row.resim4!='undefined') {
                FotoString+='&photo[]='+row.resim4;
                var resimjson=JSON.parse(row.resim4);
                data.append('photo1[]', {
                  uri:resimjson.uri,
                  type: resimjson.type, // or photo.type
                  name: 'photo'
                });
              }
              if (row.video!='' && row.video!='undefined') {
                FotoString+='&video[]='+row.video;
                var resimjson=JSON.parse(row.video);
                data.append('video1[]', {
                  uri: resimjson.uri,
                  type: resimjson.type, // or photo.type
                  name: 'video'
                });
              }
              try {

              } catch (error) {

              }


          data.append('api_token', Global.GToken); // you can append anyone.
          data.append('resid', row.id); // you can append anyone.

          data.append('additional', row.ek_aciklama); // you can append anyone.

          data.append('issue_date', row.tarih.split(' ')[0]); // you can append anyone.
          try {
            fetch("https://myapi.com/add", {
              method: 'post',
              body: data
            }).then(function(response){
              console.log(response);
             var responseJson=JSON.parse(response._bodyText)
            //  console.log();

              console.log(response);
            //  console.log(responseJson);
            //  console.log(responseJson);
              if (responseJson.sonuc == 1) {
                db.transaction((tx1) => {
                  console.log(row.id);
                  tx1.executeSql("update " + TABLO_DATA + " set gonderildi=1 where id=" + row.id + "");
                });


              } else if (responseJson.sonuc==0) {
                console.log('basarisiz');
                db.transaction((tx1) => {
                 // tx1.executeSql("update " + TABLO_DATA + " set gonderildi=1 where id=" + row.id + "");
                });
              }
            }).catch(error =>console.log(error) )
          } catch (error) {
            console.log('bb');
          }




            } catch (error) {
              console.log('ss');
            }

          }
        });
      });

    } catch (error) {
      console.log('dd');
    }
    //  const Veriler = await AsyncStorage.getItem(‘products’)
    }
```

Comment: Can you remove the commented out code in your question to make it easier to read?

Comment: Also, can you attach your error screen to this post? I didn't open that link since I don't recognize it.

Comment: didn't let me upload the screen image for new user

Comment: I got a 403 on that image

Answer (score 0):

I see the error log about the missing file but don't see how that relates to the `fetch` call. Are you POSTing that file? If so, can you clarify that in your code?

If you're not using that file in the `fetch` call, then you'll need to figure out where it is being used and why its not there.

FYI You have a `.catch` after your `fetch` which logs the errors and then prevents any `fetch` errors from getting caught in the `try/catch`.

Comment: gives error because the file has been deleted.  If the file has been deleted, I want to continue the next process instead of the error screen

Comment: Can you double-check your try/catch block in the for loop? That should handle it, but there is an extra empty `try/catch` block at the end of the loop.

Comment: I tried and not working :(.   break for loop after red error screen

Comment: Are you saying you get the error screen _after_ the `for` loop? I was assuming it would happen when the `uri` is accessed in the `data.append()`.

Comment: yes opening error screen after run fetch() code in for loop.  try catch block not working.  the code is running, but the error screen is displayed because the file cannot be found.